# LaTeXで文字を置換したい

Tags: latex

LaTeXで「。」「、」を「.」「,」に置換するコードを教えてください。
latexmkrc内に置換するコードを書きたいです。
現在latexmkrcに書いているコードも載せておきます。

```perl
$latex = 'uplatex';
$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S';
$ENV{OPENTYPEFONTS} = '/usr/share/fonts//:';
$ENV{TTFONTS} = '/usr/share/fonts//:';
```

Answer (score 0):

upLaTeXを使っておられるなら，以下の記事が参考になるかもしれません。
半角ではなく全角のカンマ・ピリオドへの置換ですが。

[upLaTeX文書の句読点を置き換える](https://doratex.hatenablog.jp/entry/20220907/1662553045)

> 文書と同フォルダにオレオレCMapを置いて代用するという雑な方法で対処するという手